# coffeescript strange behavior in subtraction

Tags: coffeescript

I must be going crazy.  Coffeescript is continualy returning '0' for the difference between two non-equal integers.

```
x = @location[0]
y = @start[0]
console.log "#{x} - #{y} = #{x-y}"
```

This is outputting:

```
350 - 322 = 0
250 - 278 = 0
... and so on
```

I'm completely confused!

Edit: Here's the source in both coffee and the compiled js

```
class Branch
    constructor: (@length, @start, @angle, @generation, @parent) ->
        return if @generation >= RECURSION_LIMIT
        @angleVariation = pi/3
        @ratio = 2/(1+root(5))
        @maxChildren = 10
        @parent ?= null
        @unit = 2
        @children = []
        @location = @start
        @childLocations = [Math.random()*@length*@ratio/2+(@length*@ratio) \
            for n in [0...@maxChildren]]

    grow: ->
        gl.beginPath()
        moveTo @location
        @location[0] += @unit * cos(@angle)
        @location[1] -= @unit * sin(@angle)
        lineTo @location
        gl.stroke()
        console.log @getLength()
        if @getLength() >= @childLocations[@children.length]
            @birthChild()


    getLength: ->
        x = @location[1]
        y = @start[1]
        console.log "#{x} - #{y} = #{x-y}"
        return 1 #root( (@location[0]-@start[0])**2 + (@location[1]-@start[1])**2 )

    birthChild: ->
        angle = @angle + (Math.random()*@angleVariation*2) - @angleVariation
        child = new Branch @length * @ratio, @location, angle, @generation+1, this
```

And in js:

```
Branch = (function() {

  function Branch(length, start, angle, generation, parent) {
    var n, _ref;
    this.length = length;
    this.start = start;
    this.angle = angle;
    this.generation = generation;
    this.parent = parent;
    if (this.generation >= RECURSION_LIMIT) {
      return;
    }
    this.angleVariation = pi / 3;
    this.ratio = 2 / (1 + root(5));
    this.maxChildren = 10;
    if ((_ref = this.parent) == null) {
      this.parent = null;
    }
    this.unit = 2;
    this.children = [];
    this.location = this.start;
    this.childLocations = [
      (function() {
        var _i, _ref1, _results;
        _results = [];
        for (n = _i = 0, _ref1 = this.maxChildren; 0 <= _ref1 ? _i < _ref1 : _i > _ref1; n = 0 <= _ref1 ? ++_i : --_i) {
          _results.push(Math.random() * this.length * this.ratio / 2 + (this.length * this.ratio));
        }
        return _results;
      }).call(this)
    ];
  }

  Branch.prototype.grow = function() {
    gl.beginPath();
    moveTo(this.location);
    this.location[0] += this.unit * cos(this.angle);
    this.location[1] -= this.unit * sin(this.angle);
    lineTo(this.location);
    gl.stroke();
    console.log(this.getLength());
    if (this.getLength() >= this.childLocations[this.children.length]) {
      return this.birthChild();
    }
  };

  Branch.prototype.getLength = function() {
    var x, y;
    x = this.location[1];
    y = this.start[1];
    console.log("" + x + " - " + y + " = " + (x - y));
    return 1;
  };

  Branch.prototype.birthChild = function() {
    var angle, child;
    angle = this.angle + (Math.random() * this.angleVariation * 2) - this.angleVariation;
    return child = new Branch(this.length * this.ratio, this.location, angle, this.generation + 1, this);
  };

  return Branch;

})();
```

Comment: Maybe you could provide the generated javascript.

Comment: Unable to reproduce (See [my JSBin](http://jsbin.com/xegix/1/edit?js,output)). Your obviously no showing us enough of the code to extrapolate. Try reproducing this problem in JSBin.com or JSFiddle.net

Comment: Ok, posted coffee source and compiled js

Comment: Solved.  

Still new to coffeescript, I was trying to copy an array's values but instead copied by reference.  I had `@location = @start` and while `@location[0]` and `@start[0]` return different values alone, the difference between the numbers is coming out 0.  Not sure if this is how coffee is suppsoed to work or not, but anyway, fixed like this:

    @location = @start.slice()